# Navigation centered in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have been trying to get the navigation on this page centered for some time now and can not figure it out. It appears to be centered in IE but in Firefox and Chrome it appears more to the left. I have tried to apply a `margin: 0 auto;` to the `#navigation` but it ignores it. Also I have tried to apply `text-align: center;` with no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions so it is cross browser compatible?

**UPDATE:** 
I removed the link to the affected website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
text-align: center;
```

to `#navigation`, when I add that in Chrome Devtools the navigation becomes centered.

Comment: this centers all the text inside of the navigation drop downs we want that text left aligned still

Comment: Add left align to the sub-menu class then

Answer (score 2):

The css property `text-align: center` will do it.
But, despite our css era, there is a element property that is still cross-browser. "Align" works for divs, so `<div align="center"></div>` will center its content.

Comment: align='center' not supported (officially) in HTML5

Comment: Yes... but in practice, still works for major browsers. But as I said, the css property has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

`.jqueryslidemenu > ul` is an inline-block object, which behaves as a word in a sentence. You can't apply `margin: auto` to a word in the middle of a sentence. Adding `text-align: center` to `.jqueryslidemenu` or `#navigation` does the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes text-align:center won't work, you can use margin:auto if it has a width!